# How do I pull a room db from my device?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I'm trying a little with the new room database helpers from Android.

So I have created all classes for the entries and the DAO as well as for the database itself.

Then I created an instance of the db in my MainActivity:

```
mDb = myDatabase.getDatabase(getApplication());
```

But when is the "physical" db-file created on the Android device?

What I want to do is to copy that file to my PC and open it in an SQLITE-mnager in oder to fill the empty database in a more comfortable way.

But I do not know where to fid it or if the file is already been created by my app (the app already produced the JSON schema file, so I expected that the db also exists).

So how do I know if it exists andhow I can pull it from my device to my PC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) It is created when you run any type of query for first time, so for example invoke any method from your DAO annotated with `@Query`, `@Insert` or other

2) Open `Device File Explorer` (you will find it on the right, down side of Android Studio) and then navigate to: `data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/databases/` where your database file will be stored, with the name that you specify in `Room.databaseBuilder` method. From this place you can right click on the file and copy it to your PC

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking

> how do I know if it exists and how I can pull it from my device to my PC

One may find this approach for viewing, modifying, and exporting a database useful, which I've taken from the Android Developer's User Guide:

**REQUIREMENTS:**

- Android Studio 4.1 or higher
- device running API level 26 or higher **OR** your app is running on an emulator

## Debug your database with the Database Inspector

In Android Studio 4.1 and higher, the Database Inspector allows you to inspect, query, and modify your app's databases while your app is running. This is especially useful for database debugging. The Database Inspector works with plain SQLite and with libraries built on top of SQLite, such as **Room**.

### Open the Database Inspector

To open a database in the Database Inspector, do the following:

1. Run your app on an emulator or connected device running API level 26 or higher.
   **Note:** A known issue related to the Android 11 emulator causes apps to crash when connecting to the DB Inspector. Help for this issue can be found here -> https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#ki-android-11-db-inspector.
2. Select View > Tool Windows > App Inspection from the menu bar.
3. Select the Database Inspector tab.
4. Select the running app process from the dropdown menu.
5. The databases in the currently running app appear in the Databases pane. Expand the node for the database that you want to inspect.

### View and modify data

The Databases pane displays a list of the databases in your app and the tables that each database contains. Double-click a table name to display its data in the inspector window to the right. You can click a column header to sort the data in the inspector window by that column.

You can modify data in a table by double-clicking a cell, typing a new value, and pressing Enter. If your app uses Room and your UI observes the database (such as with LiveData or Flow), then any changes you make to the data are visible in your running app immediately. Otherwise, changes are only visible the next time your app reads the modified data from the database.

### Export data from the Database Inspector

You can export databases, tables, and query results from the Database Inspector to save, share, or recreate locally. When you open up an app project in Android Studio and inspect the app for that project in the Database Inspector, you can start exporting data in one of the following ways:

- Select a database or table in the Databases panel and click Export to file near the top of the panel.
- Right-click on a database or table in the Databases panel and select Export to file from the context menu.
- When inspecting a table or query results in a tab, click Export to file above the table or query results.

After selecting an export action, you use the Export dialog to help you through the final steps. Depending on whether you are trying to export a database, table, or query results, you have the option of exporting the data in one or more of the following formats: DB, SQL, or CSV.

See:
https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database#view-data